# Null pointer exception component info

Tags: android, json, android-listview

Getting null pointer exception,I have declared all the activity in manifest but still error is occurred please help me to solve this problem.
error is
06-28 14:55:55.683: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 14:55:55.683: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.SingleMenuItemActivity.onCreate(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:65)

code
AndroidJsonparsingActivity.java

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity<Search> extends ListActivity {

    public class HorizontalListview {

    }

    // url to make request
    private static String url ="";

    // JSON Node names
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Bitmap bitmap1;
    Bitmap bitmap2;
    Bitmap bitmap3;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG_MOVIE = "Movies";   
    private static final String TAG_MOVIEID = "MovieId";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG_MOVIEIMAGE = "MovieImage";
    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE =  "Distance";
    private static final String TAG_PINCODE = "PinCodeNo";
    private static final String TAG_THEATERS =  "Theaters";
    private static final String TAG_THEATERSNAME =  "TheaterName";
    ImageView iv;
    ListView lv1;
    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray movies = null;
    JSONArray theaters = null;
    ImageView i,iv1,iv2,iv3;
    TextView tv;
    JSONArray dates = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        iv2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
         iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
         tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date1);
         Spinner sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        //p=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this);
        //i.setTag(imgUrl);
       // imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/84/11178428_pro.jpg", AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this,iv,);
        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> movieList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> theaterList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        bitmap = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg");
        bitmap1 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/84/11178428_pro.jpg");
        bitmap2 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/82/11178261_pro.jpg");
        bitmap3 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/82/11178261_pro.jpg");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
        iv2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        iv3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        JSONParser client = new JSONParser(
                WebServiceUrl.GetDatesForTheater2);
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = null;
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String jsonString ="";
        String jResponse = client.getStrResponse();
        // dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            JSONArray  j= json.getJSONArray(jResponse);
            //theaters = json.getJSONArray(TAG_THEATERS);
            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = j.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("val of c  " +c);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                //String id = c.getString(TAG_MOVIEID);

                //String image = c.getString(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object


                // creating new HashMap
                //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                //map.put(TAG_MOVIEID, id);
                //map.put(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE, image);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                //movieList.add(map);
            }

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jResponse);
        if(Global.showTimes.size()<=0){

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

            System.out.println(jsonarray.get(i));
            Global.showTimes.add(String.valueOf(jsonarray.get(i)));
        }
        }

        System.out.println("value of dates:->" + Global.showTimes);
            tv.setText((CharSequence) Global.showTimes);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("exception" +e);
        }
        //ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> as = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getApplicationContext(),R.id.date);
       // as.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        //as.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //sp.setAdapter(as);
 catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("this is the error" +e);
        }

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            movies = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MOVIE);
            //theaters = json.getJSONArray(TAG_THEATERS);
            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = movies.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_MOVIEID);

                //String image = c.getString(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_MOVIEID, id);
                //map.put(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE, image);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                movieList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this, movieList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_MOVIEID, TAG_MOVIEIMAGE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.image, });

        setListAdapter(adapter1);
        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts

            theaters = json.getJSONArray(TAG_THEATERS);
            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < theaters.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = theaters.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String name = c.getString(TAG_THEATERSNAME);
                String distance = c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
                String pincode = c.getString(TAG_PINCODE);
                //String image = c.getString(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                map1.put(TAG_DISTANCE,distance);
                map1.put(TAG_PINCODE,pincode);
                map1.put(TAG_THEATERSNAME,name);
                //map.put(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE, image);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                theaterList.add(map1);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        ListAdapter adapter11 = new SimpleAdapter(this, theaterList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_THEATERSNAME,TAG_DISTANCE,TAG_PINCODE}, new int[] {
                        R.id.tname,R.id.distance,R.id.pincode }); 

        setListAdapter(adapter11);

        // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    ListView lv1= getListView();
        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                //String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                //String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.image)).getText().toString();

                TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tname);
                tv.setText(TAG_THEATERSNAME);
                String name = tv.getText().toString();

                  bitmap = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/84/11178428_pro.jpg");

                  bitmap1 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/84/11178428_pro.jpg");

                  bitmap2 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/84/11178428_pro.jpg");





                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);

        in.putExtra("tname", name);
        System.out.println("THEATER NAME" +TAG_THEATERSNAME);

                startActivity(in);

            }

            private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                    URL url =new URL(src);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    return mybiBitmap;


                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return null;
                 }
            }
        });



    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            URL url =new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return mybiBitmap;


         } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
         }


    }
```

Singlemenuitemactivity.java

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {
    private static String url ="";

    Bitmap bitmap;
    Bitmap bitmap1,bitmap2,bitmap3;
    ImageView iv,iv1,iv2,iv3;
    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE =  "Distance";
    private static final String TAG_PINCODE = "PinCodeNo";
    private static final String TAG_THEATERS =  "Theaters";
    private static final String TAG_THEATERSNAME =  "TheaterName";
    //private static final String TAG_THEATERS =  "Theaters";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);
        JSONObject json = null;
        JSONArray theaters = null;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date1);
        ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> theaterList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        bitmap = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg");
        bitmap1 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/84/11178428_pro.jpg");
        bitmap2 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/82/11178261_pro.jpg");
        bitmap3 = getBitmapFromUrl("http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/17/82/11178261_pro.jpg");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
        iv2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        iv3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);
        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts

            theaters = json.getJSONArray(TAG_THEATERS);
            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < theaters.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = theaters.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String name = c.getString(TAG_THEATERSNAME);
                String distance = c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
                String pincode = c.getString(TAG_PINCODE);
                //String image = c.getString(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                map1.put(TAG_DISTANCE,distance);
                map1.put(TAG_PINCODE,pincode);
                map1.put(TAG_THEATERSNAME,name);
                //map.put(TAG_MOVIEIMAGE, image);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                theaterList.add(map1);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        ListAdapter adapter11 = new SimpleAdapter(this, theaterList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_THEATERSNAME,TAG_DISTANCE,TAG_PINCODE}, new int[] {
                        R.id.tname,R.id.distance,R.id.pincode }); 

        setListAdapter(adapter11);





      //  ListView LV=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    }
    private void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter11) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            URL url =new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return mybiBitmap;


         } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
         }
    }

}
```

Jsonparser.java

```
public class JSONParser {
    public enum RequestMethod {
        GET, POST
    }
    private String url;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    String strResponse;
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
    // constructor

    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONParser(String url) {
        this.url= url;
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }
    public String getStrResponse() {

        return strResponse;
    }

    public boolean Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception {
        boolean isExpired = false;
        switch (method) {
        case GET: {
            // add parameters
            String combinedParams = "";
            if (!params.isEmpty()) {
                combinedParams += "?";
                for (NameValuePair p : params) {
                    String paramString = p.getName() + "="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(), "UTF-8");
                    if (combinedParams.length() > 1) {
                        combinedParams += "&" + paramString;
                    } else {
                        combinedParams += paramString;

                    }
            }
            }
        }
        }
        return isExpired;
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
    public void AddParam(String name, String value) {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized

```
JSONObject json = null;
```

before using it in

```
 theaters = json.getJSONArray(TAG_THEATERS);
```

As a result you are getting `NullPointerException`. You probably want to get some data and store it in `json`

Comment: no,i have declared json object before using it,still m getting this error

Comment: You have declared it but you haven't initialized anywhere in that `Activity` as far as i can see. For eg. you have done `json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` in `AndroidJSONParsingActivity` but you haven't done anything like that in `SingleMenuItemActivity`